# Is my Xamarin.Forms application of the correct project type?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Feeling like a real idiot :-)

I started Xamarin.Forms app.
My App structure (according solution explorer) is as follows:

Connected Services
Properties
References
Controllers (I added this)
Models (I added this)
Assets
Resources
MainActivity.cs

My main activty has the following in-code definition structure:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

The Main Activity's constructor looks like follows:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Also, my layouts are .XML files. Not .XAML files.

So my first question:

1. Does this correspond to a standard Xamarin.Forms app? Or did I choose the wrong project type. I can find no way of identifying the project type *post* creation. My first guess it that this is where I made the mistake. Just not sure what went wrong.
2. Assuming the project is correct, how do I access the App / Application / Page references / variables

All references I get in searching directs me to class definitions as follows:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage {
```

Would appreciate any guidance.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are novice in Xamarin you must need to follow documents provided my Xamarin team. Check these links here, it will help you to get start with xamarin.

1. [Create a Xamarin.Forms application quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/app?pivots=windows)
2. [Build your first Xamarin.Forms App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows)

Comment: From your links it would seem I have the Xamarin Android project only, not the Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Its simple if you have 3 projects in solution its Xamarin.Forms project otherwise its native either Android or iOS.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Appreciate the quick and concise confirmation. I will have to port it :-( :-)